# Unexpected result for Coefficient[]

Tags: polynomials

Is this just me being stupid, or is this a known bug in Mathematica?

```
Coefficient[2 x + 2 y, x + y]
```

gives 0, while

```
Coefficient[2(x + y), x + y]
```

gives 2. The documentation says that it should work whenever the expression is expanded or not...

I can see the problem with
    Coefficient[x-y, x + y]
but if all coefficients in *expr* and *form* are positive, then surely there is a well-defined largest number k, such that `expr-k*form` have non-negative coefficients? And this is what I'd expect.

```
Coefficient[expr,form]
```

EDIT:
In my case,

```
PolynomialReduce[expr,{form},vars][[1,1]]
```

does the thing I want. This computes *k* such that *expr-k form* is minimal in some sense.

Comment: Can you write a minimal example of this behaviour?

Comment: As noted in the tag description, please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag until your problem has been verified by other people.

Comment: Fixed, a much smaller example that captures the problem, I think.

Comment: So, how 'bout marking this as a bug now?

Comment: No, give it more time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I deleted my first answer because I somehow made a mistake testing the OP's original input.]

[*Edit:* The OP substituted a simpler example, so I deleted my analysis of the original one and substituted another simpler but similar example.]

One question has to do with how `Coefficient[expr, form]` matches terms of `expr` to a given `form`.  For instance, the "form" of `3x + 3y` is quite a bit different than `x + y`, which has no coefficients multiplying the variables.  Indeed, on this example (somewhat like the original one), observe the following:

```
poly = (x + y + z + 2)^2;
poly2 = x + y;

Coefficient[poly + poly2, poly2]
Coefficient[poly + poly2 // Expand, poly2]
Coefficient[poly + poly2, 2 poly2]
```

> ```
> 1
> 0
> 5/2 + z
> ```

So `2 Coefficient[poly + poly2, 2 poly2]` gives the correct answer, which is an awkward workaround.

But here's an even stranger behavior that seems just plain wrong to me:

```
Coefficient[4 x + 2 y + 2 z, 2 (x/2 + y/2)]
Coefficient[4 x + 2 y + 2 z, x + y]
```

> ```
> 4
> 0
> ```

In the first form, it seems the second term is ignored, even if it's nonsense:

```
Coefficient[4 x + 2 y + 2 z, 2 (x + t)]
Coefficient[4 x + 2 y + 2 z, 2 (x + Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}])]
```

> ```
> 2
> 2
> ```

---

In `Coefficient[expr, form]`, there seems to be something odd in the way `form` matches terms of `expr` when `form` involves `Plus`.  I have not found an example in the reference manual in which `form` simplifies to a sum of terms.  Perhaps it's not intended to be used this way.

Comment: Yeah, it really is strange, but the lack of a warning is what is really annoying.