# Changes to Coefficient function in v10.2

Tags: polynomials

In the version *Mathemaica* 10.4, I am very surprised that the core function `Coefficient` has changed, e.g.,

```
Coefficient[3 x x + 8 y y - 24 x y, 2 x y]
```

> 0

In previous versions (e.g. v9.0.1, v10.1.0), the result was `-12`. On the website [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), the result is still `-12`. According to comments, it seems like the change has happened from v10.1.0 to v10.2.0.

Yes, this change is very small, but I feel it is very dangerous for my previous research code. How do I know about these kind of changes in new versions? Is there a list explaining such changes?

Comment: v10.4.1 gives `0` also. Any change occurred prior to v11.0

Comment: I know v10.4.0 gives -12.  Anyway, this core function has changed.

Comment: It must be system-dependent because v10.4.0 and v10.4.1 on my Mac gives `0`

Comment: `WolframLanguageData["Coefficient", "VersionLastModified"]` returns `3`. Therefore any change since v10.4.1 might not had been intentional.

Comment: On my Mac the change appears to have occurred going from 10.1.0 to 10.2.0

Comment: @Karsten7. I don't know what meaning of your `3`,But as `WolframLanguageData["Coefficient", "DateLastModified"]`, we can see wolfram have not change this function.

Comment: @yode, since it is the result of `"VersionLastModified"`, it means the function was last changed in version 3.

Comment: `Coefficient[3 x x + 8 y y - 24 x y, 2 x y]` evaluates to `-12` in 10.1.0 under Windows 7 x64, which agrees with Bob Hanlon's result.

Comment: I don't see `2*x*y` occuring in `24*x*y`.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the result 0 is more reasonable. Or we can think new version mathematica just fixed a bug for this function ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the behavior the OP is reporting is not a change from V10

Comment: @m_goldberg What's this behavior in your opinion ?  I am still very curious about this problem.

Comment: There is no problem.

Comment: Dear @m_goldberg,If this is not a probelm? why v10.1.0 and v11 give different results?
Maybe I am dumb. I don't understand why 0 is more reasonable?
And I see '2*x*y' in '12*x*y'.
Please give this problem more time before voting to close it, it doesn't hurt, right?

Comment: Looks like a classic case of "undefined behavior". `Coefficient` wasn't meant to be used that way, so the outcome can change between versions, maybe even different runs of the same version.

Comment: V10.4 also gives zero. Nothing changed between V10.4 and V11.

Comment: v9.0.1 yields -12

Comment: What @nikie said. This is very much in the "undefined behavior" realm. In this instance, the old behavior was lost due to a bug fix that involved something slightly closer to intended usage.

Comment: Is [(26510)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26510/121) affected by this change/fix?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  No. I have know that problem for a long time. So, to be safe, when I used Cofficient[exp], I always need to ExpandAll the exp. But, here, more seriously, the result is different with the previous version. Some rule for this function has been changed ?  I am not sure.

Comment: @Orders Related: [103018](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103018/workaround-for-issues-with-coefficient-in-10-0-2?rq=1). Personally, I can understand your concerns very well. I think that it is a very poor practice to change behavior of core functions without putting any announcements to the changelog.

Comment: voted to close as I don't see there is any way to answer other than speculation, and it shouldn't be sitting on the unanswered list.   BTW can anyone likes the old behavior explain why `Coefficient[ x y,  2. x y ]` gives `.5` and `Coefficient[ x y,  Pi x y ]` is zero?